# How should I handle this HTTPS request in Python?

Tags: python, https, urllib, getaddrinfo

I am trying to use the [Strava API v3](http://strava.github.io/api/v3/) in Python, and I am afraid I am missing something. The docs say:

> This base URL is used for all Strava API requests:
> https://api.strava.com
>
> ```
> $ curl -i https://api.strava.com
> ```
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: application/json Status: 200 OK
> X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000 X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4999 Content-Length: 2
> ```
>
> Responses are in JSON format and gzipped.

I am currently doing this:

```
import urllib
print urllib.urlopen('https://api.strava.com').read()
```

And gettin this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "StravaAPIv3.py", line 3, in <module>
    print urllib.urlopen('https://api.strava.com').read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 86, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 207, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 436, in open_https
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 776, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1157, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

I don't know where to start, since I don't know much about HTTP requests and HTTPS

UPDATE: According to Merlin's suggestion to use `requests` module, I am doing this:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.strava.com/')
print r.status_code
print r.headers['content-type']
print r.encoding
print r.text
print r.json()
```

but keep getting an error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.strava.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'so cket.gaierror'>: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow the instructions here first: http://strava.github.io/api/v3/oauth/
Basically, the app you create has to authorize the user using it (in this case, you). I've written some example code below. I'm new to python so don't know how to automate log in, so you'll have to copy and paste the url to the browser and copy and paste the code in.

```
import requests
import json

#Replace #### with your client id (listed here: http://www.strava.com/settings/api)
#Replace &&&& with your redirect uri listed on the same page. I used localhost
#Go this url in your browser and log in. Click authorize
https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=###&response_type=code&redirect_uri=&&&&

#Copy and paste the code returned in the url
code='qwertyuio123456789'
#Replace @@@@ with the code on your api page
values={'client_id':'###', 'client_secret':  '@@@@', 'code':code}
r = requests.post('https://www.strava.com/oauth/token', data=values)
json_string = r.text.replace("'", "\"")
values = json.loads(json_string)

#now you have an access token
r = requests.get('http://www.strava.com/api/v3/athletes/227615', params=values)
```

Have fun!

Comment: That seems promising. Gonna test it as soon as I can and give some feedback here. Thanks!

Comment: Could you just tell me how could I use the "localhost" thing to get the codes? I got a bad request error...

Comment: You need to set a callback url in the strava api setting page. It is the website strava will redirect the user to once they have authorized. Since you are doing this in python, this doesn't matter. So just set the callback url to localhost, both in the url string and on the settings page on your account.

Comment: I've got it... The problem is that I should have asked to REGISTER my application in the first place. But currently Strava is limiting registration just to a few developers... Well, thank you very much for your help, but I'll have to wait a little bit, it seems...

Answer (score 3):

Try using requests! It's safer. 
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: Getting this error: `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.strava.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'so
cket.gaierror'>: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed)`

Comment: I have edited the question with the code I used that generated this error.

Comment: Well, it seems the thing is too brittle at the moment (although they intend to release this in June...). +1 for a robust http module, then! (I installed it easily with PIP)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [httplib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html).  Sample code to get to a HTTPS server:

```
import httplib

con = httplib.HTTPSConnection('www.google.com')
con.request("GET", "/")
res = con.getresponse()
print res.read()
```

Comment: Getting this error: `httplib.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: '//api.strava.com/'`

Comment: Is the URL correct?  I get a "webpage" not available when I try that URL in the browser and `ping api.strava.com` comes back with "Unknown host"